# Unauthorised 401 on ASP.Net MVC App opening Windows Authentication box despite Forms authentication being used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

To provide some backstory we have an ASP.Net MVC Application that is used by many customers and for each one it is installed on a server on their network.  There are permissions setup within the application and if anyone tries to access something or do something they don't have permission to do the server side code of web api returns

```
throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
```

This is working perfectly well and never had an issue with it in 2+ years over the 30+ customers using it.  However, on one customer when this exception is thrown the windows authentication box pops up asking for username/password even though its not set in IIS or web.config.  Clicking cancel gets rid of it and they can carry on as normal so the authentication is not actually affected.

Has anyone ever come across this? Any suggestions would be welcome.

EDIT: Web.config (Only authentication entry)

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" name=".DatabridgeSPA" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Which authentications do you see in "enabled" status in IIS for this website?

Comment: @Nirman Forms and Anonymous. As I say Windows Authentication is not enabled.

Comment: Please add the relevant `web.config` sections so we can see how authentication is actually configured.

Comment: Does it happen on any specific browser or across different browsers? Is this customer on a different OS?

Comment: @AmanB On Windows Server and IIS. Seems to be all browsers.

Comment: I hate this site, why do people give negative votes without any reason? It really puts you off asking for help on here.

Comment: Is anonymousAuthentication enabled in IIS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/anonymousauthentication

Comment: @AmanB Yes it is